# Limiting number of rows read from a CSV file with async/await function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer in order to scrape a webpage with async/await method.

In order to scrape the data, I have first to search over 600 values using the webpage’s browser, so I created a CSV file containing the values.

I import the csv-parser to read the file and then declare a String out of every row in the csv so I can later search the content of each String in the browser.

This is the code I managed to put together:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
(async function main (){
    try{        
    fs.createReadStream('values.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', async function (data) {
            const str = String(data.Row1)

// … Here’s the code to open headless Chrome and open the webpage (working fine)

// Code to type in the string into the search bar and click the search button:

await page.type('#SearchBar', str);
await page.click('#SearchButton');

// … Here’s the code to scrape the data displayed after each search (working fine)
});
})();
```

When I ran the code it tried to open over 600 headless browsers and the following message appeared:

> (node:9568) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

I then tried to read a CSV file with only 10 rows and it worked fine. But I need to include all the 600 values into the file, so I tried to limit the number of searches to 10 by making the function take a callback as its second parameter using the async module, but it didn’t work.

¿How can I asynchronously search for 10 values at a time, that is, limiting the reading to 10 rows per iteration?

I apologize if I didn’t formulate my question clearly enough or if there’s an easier way to achieve the same goal, but I have zero experience in coding and I’m just trying to develop a tool for my parents’ office before I leave next year.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code that launches the browser outside the `data` callback and put this logic into the `finish` callback. In the `data` callback just buffer the data to an array that you can `slice` later.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
(async function main (){
    try{
    var searchTerms = [];        
    fs.createReadStream('values.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function (data) {
            const str = String(data.Row1)
            searchTerms.push(str);
     })
     .on('finish', function() {

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var searchTermsChunk = searchTerms.slice(i*60, (i+1)*60);
  (async function(searchTermsChunk) {
    searchTermsChunk.forEach(function(str) {
      // … Here’s the code to open headless Chrome and open the webpage (working fine)

      // Code to type in the string into the search bar and click the search button:

       await page.type('#SearchBar', str);
       await page.click('#SearchButton');

      // … Here’s the code to scrape the data displayed after each search (working fine)
    });
  })(searchTermsChunk);
}
});
})();
```

I haven't tested this code, so it may not work out of the box. The general idea is that in the `finish` event handler you slice your data into 10 chunks. Each `searchTermsChunk` contains 60 elements (last chunk may be smaller). For each chunk you create an async function, so 10 async functions in total. Inside each async function you iterate over the elements of the chunk and wait for the completion of page events.

Hope it helps.